# Is it possible to store a value from a promise to a outside variable

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to store a value from a promise to a outside variable

```
 var hwid;
    getHWID().then(id => {
    console.log(id)
    })
```

I want the id in the hwid variable so i can check it against a mysql database

Comment: `await` the Promise

Comment: Yes, it's possible, [but pointless](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron). Just store the promise itself in the variable.

Comment: Of course, you can, but since Promises are all about time, how do you know when the value will be available? Now you need some state that tells you wether the value is already available or not, and maybe some EventDispatcher so you can register to an event and get notified when `hwid` is available, ... you see a pattern? You're basically re-building a Promise. Just use the Promise